# How to playback 4K Youtube videos in 4K quality in Google Chrome on a 4K display?

Tags: youtube

I have Chrome, version 76 as of writing this, on Windows 10, all updates installed.

I have 2x 4K displays, one Asus MG28U and one Samsung U28E590. I have set my Nvidia 1060 graphics card to display in 4K, 200% font sizing.

All this works wonders. I have crystal clear 4K text and graphics in all applications, including Google Chrome and websites.

Except for one thing, when I look at Youtube videos that has both 4K in the title and also this 4K small label, the quality choices go up to 1080 and no higher.

[image: Youtube video with 4K label]

[image: Youtube video quality choices, no 4K option]

Is there a trick to enabling this? I tried to see if changing font scaling to 100% enabled it but that does not alter this outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YouTube has removed the option to set your preferred video quality during playback**.

At the moment it is only possible if you use some extension, add-on or plugin. Please have a look at the [Chrome Extensions](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/youtube%20hd) under "YouTube HD".

### EDIT

You should **also check whether your system supports the VP9 codec**. *(It is what YouTube uses since it is royalty-free)*.
If it doesn't, the video will be downscaled.

Comment: I wouldn't think this had anything to do with *preferred* video playback quality as 4K isn't even available to me. Also, according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VP9) page, VP9 should be supported on my system, but it also mentions Edge. I tried the same video as I showed examples from in my question and sure enough, Edge allows 4K. I guess Chrome doesn't allow it though. I will check out that extension.

Comment: After looking over the extensions and checking the rights they require I think I'll resort to using Edge when viewing Youtube.

Comment: Ho hum. I have no idea what happened but after checking 4K support in Edge, Chrome suddenly gave me the options as well, guess it thought I was checking out the competition. Must've been some odd configuration on my computer or whatnot.

Comment: @LasseVågsætherKarlsen Glad it worked out. _"...guess it thought I was checking out the competition"_ I just loved this concise, very concrete, well documended, scientifically tested way of thinking. hehehe. You made my day. `:)` Thank you.

Comment: It helps to anthropomorphize my computer, much easier to explain that he's just being stupid, instead of me having done something stupid. Which of course never happens. No sir. (spills coffee)